# Randomize quick sort in python, recursion issue

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, quicksort

I am implementing randomized quick sort. For now I have created a function `ChoosePivot(A,N)`. This returns a random pivot and its location in input array. Then I switch that random pivot with first element in array so that pivot in `Partition (A,l,r)` is always first element. For Now `ChoosePivot(A,N)` is also returning first element of the array but I plan to modify it later.

Following is my code:

```
def QuickSort(A,N):
    if (N == 1):
        return
    pivot, pivot_pos = ChoosePivot(A,N)
    l = 0
    r = len(A)
    # Preprocessing, swapping pivot position with first element so that first element remains pivot always
    temp = A[0]
    A[0] = A[pivot_pos]
    A[pivot_pos] = temp

    A, i= Partition(A,l,r)
    print A,i
    # If i-1 == 0 this means that there is no left subarray
    if (i-1 != 0):
        print "Unsorted array"
        print A[0:i-1]
        QuickSort(A[0:i-1],i-1)
        print "Left call"
        print A

    if (N-i !=0): 
        print "Unsorted array"
        print A[i:N]
        QuickSort (A[i:N], N-i)
        print "Right call"
        print A
```

Following is my `Partition(A,l,r)`

```
def Partition(A,l,r):
    # Now first element is the pivot
    i= l + 1
    pivot = A[l]
    for j in range(l+1, r):
        if (A[j] < pivot):
            #swap (A[j], A[i])
            temp_1 = A[i]
            A[i] = A[j]
            A[j] = temp_1
            i = i+1
    #swap (A[i-1], A[l])
    temp_2 = A[i-1]
    A[i-1] = A[l]
    A[l] = temp_2
    return A, i
```

`ChoosePivot(A,N)` Simply returns the first element in array for now

```
def ChoosePivot(A, N):
    #print A
    return A[0], 0
```

Input array I used is as follows:

```
Test_in = [3,8,2,5,1,4,7,6]
print Test_in

QuickSort(Test_in, len(Test_in))
print Test_in
```

Please see that I can see code working at lower end of recursion. I did dry run code with pen and paper and I can see with print statements that it does sort the sub arrays but when array is returned finally, it has not changed. I thought its something related to value vs  reference calling but I found that python calls by reference. So there should not be any problem there. 
Posting output as well and pointing out exactly where it went wrong.

[image]

Comment: Please do not give a link to an image, post the text of the problem in your question.

Comment: I do not intent to post link. I took image of the console and pointed out exactly where code has problem but SO does not allow me to post image unless I have some points. So it posted the link by itself

Comment: Don't. Copy and paste the text from the image into your question.  The reason is that we can't do that, and to reproduce your problem we would have to type it all in ourselves.  The more barriers you put in place the less likely it is that anyone will try to help.

Comment: Sorry, Let me clarify .This image no one needs to type. If someone runs the code. This will be output. Image I posted, just in case someone does not even need to run the code and can point out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug.
Problem is when I call `QuickSort` again, I slice the original list and pass it as argument. When list is sliced python creates a new list and copied the sliced list into new list with same name. All changes happen in the new list deep within the recursion so they are not reflected back to the top.
As solution I passed entire array and passed the list indices as arguments to the array.

There was still another bug. Condition before calling `QuickSort` which is `i-1!=0` and `N-i!=0` are not correct as pivot could be any index in array. I created separate left and right indices for left and right subarray and tested `left_index < right_index`.

Thanks